# Angular form not submitting via post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, http-post

Please check why this angular code does not submit url via post. I am trying to send my form details through sms, to post a request via mobile.

```
<div id="page7-container1" ng-app="amApp">
      <h4 id="page7-heading1" style="color:#000000;">App</h4>
      <div id="page7-markdown3" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
      </div>
      <div id="page7-markdown6" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
      </div>
      <div id="page7-markdown5" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
      </div>
      <div id="page7-markdown4" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
      </div>
      <h3 id="page7-heading4" style="color:#337AE2;font-weight:600;">Request a call back</h3>
      <form id="page7-form2" class="list" ng-controller="formCtrl" ng-submit="submitForm()">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" id="page7-input0">
          <input type="text" name="formAdata.rname" required placeholder="Enter Your Name">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" id="page7-input1">
          <input type="number" name="formAdata.rmobile" required placeholder="Enter Mobile Number">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" id="page7-input2">
          <input type="text" name="formAdata.rlocation" required placeholder="Enter Your location/district/state?">
        </label>
        <input id="page7-button12" type="submit" ngClick="Submit" class="button button-positive  button-block" value="Request call back!">
      </form>
        <script language="javascript">
            var messager = '';
            var app = angular.module('amApp', []);
            app.controller('formCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.submitForm = function() {
                    messager = "http://amritamultimedia.co.in/sms/sendsms.php?uid=9947009540&pwd=A3228B&msg=I am "+$scope.formAdata.rName+" from "+$scope.formAdata.rLocation+". My mobile number is: "+$scope.formAdata.rMobile+", I would like to get more info about Courses. Requested call back from your Mobile App, Please call me to my mobile.";
                    $http({
                        url: messager,
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        data: $.param($scope.formAdata)
                    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        document.getElementById("page7-form2").innerHTML = "We will get back to you within 3-4 hours. Thanks for checking our app.";
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    });
                };
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

What must be missing, or what am doing wrong?

Please help!

Thanks,
Sj

Comment: use `ngClick="submitForm()"` instead of `ngClick="Submit()"` on submit button

Answer (score 1):

add this to your controller

```
$scope.formAdata={};
```

your using json parameters, so your formAdata doesn't gets binded properly.

Also check you are using **POST** but passing the data like a **query string**, so need to bindand send as a json object or use **GET** method.

One more thing double check if the value of messenger is getting assigned or not since there is no datatype is mentioned

```
var app = angular.module('amApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formAdata={};
    var messager = "";
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        messager = "http://amritamultimedia.co.in/sms/sendsms.php;
        var userData={
        "uid":mobilenumber,
        "pwd":password,
        "phone":$scope.formAdata.phone,
        "msg": $scope.formAdata.message
        }
        $http({
            url: messager,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: userData,
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            document.getElementById("page7-form2").innerHTML = "We will get back to you within 3-4 hours. Thanks for checking our app.";
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
    };
});
```

This will work.

Comment: let me check...will get back to you.. Thanks Aravind

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, but does not work in currect scenario. Now let me explain what am trying to get... Am using a github plugin to connect with way2sms to send sms to get client request to mobile. It works fine when the url is given in browser url and submitted. But is it possible to do that via angular post method while submitting form....? Hope you got the real issue....

The following url works fine when submitted from browser url, which am trying to use from angular submit...

http://amritamultimedia.co.in/sms/sendsms.php?uid=9947009540&pwd=A3228B&phone=9947009540&msg=Hello+World

Comment: am trying to build an app using this...am not sure how could i debug error out of this. Am using ionic framework and phonegap to build app.

Comment: are you allowed to use team viewer??

Comment: I can post ionic template for this page...? is it ok?

Comment: You can check this shared device here...
https://app.testobject.com/#/share/75b815fa-e189-45ea-92c3-10ed1fb8840b/device

Comment: are you a member in slack ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127999/discussion-between-yjs-and-aravind).